# Proof/explanation that Sun is bigger and more distant from Earth than Moon is, Middle Age technology allowed only

Tags: astronomy, history, geometry, solar-system, eclipse

If I was living in the Middle Ages, how can someone prove or at least explain to me in a simple way that the Sun is bigger and more far from Earth than the Moon?

Can a parallax be used for it?

$$\text{ratio}_1=\frac{\text{diameter}_\text{sun}}{\text{diameter}_\text{moon}}=400.8$$

$$\text{ratio}_2=\frac{\text{distance}_\text{earth-sun}}{\text{distance}_\text{earth-moon}}=385.2$$

$\text{ratio}_2$ is only $3.9$ % lower than $\text{ratio}_1$.

I know that there were four astronomers, that were important in developing the right opinions about the mutual positions and movements: Nicolas Copernicus, Tycho Brahe, Johannes Kepler, Galileo Galilei.

Comment: Eclipses, man. Eclipses. How can the moon shadow the sun, if it aint in front of it.

Comment: wow a lot of inadmissible theorems. very nice question. https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/116019/inadmissible-theorems-in-research/116035#116035

Answer (score 15):

As the answer by Jonas pointed out, a solar eclipse is an obvious way to realise that the Sun must be further away than the Moon and hence larger, since their angular size is almost the same.

However, this does not tell you how much larger and further away the Sun is. The most basic way I have heard of, but which is hard to measure with ancient technology, is to realise that the Moon is lit by the Sun, and that seeing a half-moon means we have a right triangle, with the right angle between the axis Moon-Earth and Moon-Sun. You can then try to estimate the angle between the axis Moon-Earth and Earth-Sun, which basically appears to be close to $90^\circ$, which would render the Sun infinitely far way. Aristarchus, an ancient Greek, measured an angle of $87^\circ$, rendering the ratio of distance to be around $1/\cos(87^\circ)\approx20$, see [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristarchus_of_Samos#Distance_to_the_Sun)

Comment: Related question, echoing the end of your answer: [Why does the light side of the moon appear not to line up correctly with the evening sun?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/6969/21441)

Comment: @Ruslan I understand that this a projection phenomenon... straight lines in space are not necessarily projected onto 'straight lines' at the sky. However, I never thought about how this may make the measurement of the angles harder.

Answer (score 12):

Easy to measure since ancient times are the angular diameters of sun
($0.53°$) and moon ($0.52°$), which happen to be nearly equal to each other.

This gives you
$$\frac{\text{diameter}_\text{sun}}{\text{distance}_\text{earth-sun}}
=0.53°\frac{2\pi}{360°}=0.0093 \tag{1}$$
$$\frac{\text{diameter}_\text{moon}}{\text{distance}_\text{earth-moon}}
=0.52°\frac{2\pi}{360°}=0.0090 \tag{2}$$

Historically, the next thing determined was the distance of the moon.
This was first done by measuring the [parallax of the moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_distance_(astronomy)#History_of_measurement)
(i.e. the apparent position difference of the moon
in the sky when viewed from two different
locations on earth at the same time).
[image: parallax of the moon]
<sub>(image from [Lunar Parallax](http://www.etwright.org/astro/moonpar.html))</sub>

The difficult part here was to figure out how to do these
two observations at the same time even before choronometers
were invented.
When observing the moon from different continents
(i.e. separated by a distance $s$ of several $1000$ km)
you measure a parallax $\delta$ between $1°$ and $2°$,
which is easily detectable even without a telescope.
From this you can calculate the distance of the moon by
$\text{distance}=\frac{s}{\delta}\frac{360°}{2\pi}$
and get $$\text{distance}_\text{earth-moon}=380{,}000\text{ km}.$$

The parallax of the sun can be measured in the same way as above.
But it is much more difficult because the measured parallax
$\delta$ of the sun turns  out to be much smaller
(between $0.002°$ and $0.005°$ when measured from different continents).
From this result you already see without any calculation
that the sun must be much further away than the moon.
When calculating the distance of the sun by
$\text{distance}=\frac{s}{\delta}\frac{360°}{2\pi}$
you get $$\text{distance}_\text{earth-sun}=150{,}000{,}000\text{ km}.$$

From these distances of moon and sun you can, by using (1) and (2),
calculate their diameters and find
$$\text{diameter}_\text{moon}=3{,}400\text{ km}$$
$$\text{diameter}_\text{sun}=1{,}400{,}000\text{ km}.$$

Comment: You seem to be mixing conventions for your thousands separators and decimal points. All your distances use . for the thousands separator, but everything else seems to use . for a decimal point. You might want to stick to one convention!

Comment: Indeed, there is a different notation for that in different countries: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Comment: @Hearth Yes, sorry. Now using the English thousand separator convention.

Comment: @JanN. Yes, I'm aware; it's not really a problem as long as you're consistent with it, I brought it up because both the English and the European convention were being mixed in this same answer, which runs the risk of being confusing.

Comment: Whatever the use of comma inside a number, it should be typeset without spaces around it. I.e. $1{,}400{,}000$ instead of $1,400,000$. Otherwise it's just a sequence of numbers. (Use _Show Math As_ → _TeX Commands_ to learn the difference in code.)

Comment: @Ruslan Thanks for this bit

Answer (score 11):

On a solar eclipse, the moon moves in front of the sun. From that it should be obvious that it must be closer to earth than the sun. From everyday experience it should also be clear that if two objects appear roughly the same size (which could perhaps even be observed with the naked eye, but **don't do that**), but one of them is farther away, it must be larger.

Comment: "These cows are small. These cows are far awaaay." (Father Ted)

Comment: Do we (approximately) know since when people were aware that the sun is actively shining whereas the moon is just reflecting light? Otherwise it would be impossible to distinguish the mechanism behind the lunar eclipse and the solar eclipse IMHO.